# Should I separate my data into different batches and then perform tsne on each batch?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I have a very huge dataset and required to reduce the embedding of 768 dimension to 128dimension with TSNE. Since I have more than 1million rows, it takes more than weeks to complete dimension reduction on whole dataset, so I thought maybe I can separate the dataset into different parts and then perform each part separately. I do not have GPU so only CPU.

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
tsne = TSNE(n_components=128, init='pca', random_state=1001, perplexity=30, method='exact', n_iter=250, verbose=1)
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(df_dataset[:1000000]) # this will either fail or take a while (most likely overnight)
```

I am wondering whether my way is considered OK?

Also, I check the below link about whitening sentence representation but not sure whether does it work with my above method by replacing tsne with whitening.
https://deep-ch.medium.com/dimension-reduction-by-whitening-bert-roberta-5e103093f782

Comment: Have you considered using random projections?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, that is probably not a way to handle the TSNE reduction. The TSNE algorithm is a pairwise operator. So, breaking up the observations removes data for the remaining data in this set to pair with, not only removing opportunities to reduce but biasing how it does based on the chunks you create to carry out this process.

A better way to do this would be to rent compute in the cloud and make use of multithreading with cores. This allows for a single point of control over what is done, and faster completion. It costs money, but that is the expense of doing big data well, fast and efficiently!

Sagemaker in AWS has a full python environment where you can provision and run this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not had to use this, there's a reference to large datasets being approachable using random walk in the [original t-SNE paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf)

Chapter 5 of that paper has the details.